# Building a scraper, what if a page doesn't use jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm working on a scraper and I'd like to scrape certain sites but using jQuery on an ID or class doesn't return anything, meaning they're not using jQuery on their site.

How do I build my scraper for the sites that don't use jQuery, like CNN or Instapaper.com, for example?

I've tried `$$` but I can't seem to figure out methods to call on that to get things like children or the value of the div.

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inject jQuery yourself.**

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js";
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(script);
```

*Note:* This works perfectly good as a browser bookmark as well - when debugging applications that don't use jQuery, this works wonders.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jQueryfy](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet). It seems to do exacly what you need. But using native javascript might be even a better idea.